# Filter 2 MySQL Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

have anyone here tried to filter a table using a field on a separate table? e.g. Table_1 has field of login,group,name and Table_2 has field of login,volume,profit,open_time,close_time.

since Table_2 doesn't have a group i want to filter the login by group so that the result on the query would be filtered already. i have tried the statement below which has no errors but returns no result.

```
"SELECT DISTINCT a.LOGIN, a.GROUP, b.LOGIN, b.SYMBOL,
       SUM(b.VOLUME) NetVolume, SUM(b.PROFIT) NetProfit, b.CLOSE_TIME 
 FROM TABLE_1 a, TABLE_2 b
 WHERE b.CLOSE_TIME BETWEEN '"+dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+"' AND '"+ dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+"' AND 
       a.GROUP NOT IN('group_a','group_b') AND
       a.LOGIN = b.LOGIN
   ORDER BY NetVolume";
```

I hope someone can help me on this.

Thanks...

Comment: General comment: You are concatenating together your query which might open the possibility of SQL injection.  Consider using prepared statements.

Comment: im ok with this because this is an internal program written on vb.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use INNER JOIN

So it would look something like

```
    SELECT DISTINCT a.LOGIN, a.GROUP, b.LOGIN, b.SYMBOL,
        SUM(b.VOLUME) NetVolume, SUM(b.PROFIT) NetProfit, b.CLOSE_TIME 
    FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.LOGIN = b.LOGIN 
    WHERE b.CLOSE_TIME BETWEEN '"+dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+"' AND '"+ dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+"' AND a.GROUP NOT IN('group_a','group_b') AND
   ORDER BY NetVolume";
```

For more about joins in MySql check 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.  It doesn't address the question directly.

You have two major errors in the code:

1. *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.
2. Use parameters to pass values into the query.

You may need a `LEFT JOIN`, but you can't express this using commas.

In addition:

- `SELECT DISTINCT` is almost never needed with `GROUP BY`.
- The `GROUP BY` does not have all the unaggregated columns.

You should work on writing a clean query.  This might actually fix your underlying problem.  The problem is probably due to the parameter values that are passed in.